# how to pass String values from (Servlet) java class to file.jsp in maven Project?

Tags: jsp, maven, servlets, web-applications, jsp-tags

I have 2 files named bulletedList.java and blist.jsp in my maven project as web application.

My linked .jsp file to .java file. and have a button to generate numbers as soon as i press that button then .java file generates 4 random numbers and converts them to string. Then comes the stage where i want to use those generated values in jsp file as bulleted list but i am unable to do this.

The code of bulletedList.java(servlet) is:

```
public BulletedList() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<title>My BulletedList Servlet!</title>");

    String No1 = "" + ((int) (Math.random() * 50));
    String No2 = "" + ((int) (Math.random() * 25));
    String No3 = "" + ((int) (Math.random() * 75));
    String No4 = "" + ((int) (Math.random() * 99));

    response.getWriter().write(No1);
    response.getWriter().write(No2);
    response.getWriter().write(No3);
    response.getWriter().write(No4);

    response.sendRedirect("bList.jsp");

    //out.println("<h1>" + request.getParameter("No1") + "</h1>");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

now i don't know what do i need to do to use those values in jsp file and display them in browser.

i tried this:

request.getParameter(No1) after (LI) tag but it just displayed plain No1 as text instead of displaying any random value stored in it that was generated by math.random().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use **redirect**

> The redirect sends a header back to the browser / client. This header contains the resource url to be redirected by the browser. Then the browser initiates a new request to the given url. Since it is a new request, the old request and response object is lost.

Use:

```
RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("bList.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: but i still don't get why this: {getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("bList.jsp").forward(request, response);} did not worked

Comment: `request.getRequestDispatcher()` is taking the relative path of the url as argument _(Ex- /bList.jsp)_ whereas `context.getRequestDispatcher()` is taking the absolute path of the url as argument._(Ex- /Package/bList.jsp)_

Comment: So if you want to use _context requestDispatcher_ you have to provide full path of the jsp. ie `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher (“/ContextRoot/jsp/bList.jsp”);`

Answer (score 1):

First forward the request to the JSP, rather than sending a redirect:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("bList.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Your current code will tell the browser to make a brand new request for the bList.jsp, without invoking your servlet.

Then set your values on the request scope, rather than writing them to *out*:

```
request.setAttribute("no1", No1);
request.setAttribute("no2", No2);
```

In your JSP (which essentially just another servlet in the request chain) you can access these attributes and embed them within your HTML markup.

```
<li><%= pageContext.getRequest().getAttribute("no1") %></li>
```

But even better, and the preferred way, is to use the JSP expression language instead to access or output request scope attriubtes:

```
<li>${no1}</li>
```

Comment: it worked very thanks but i had to use @Zeeshan's RequestDispatcher code otherwise it was still giving null values.

Comment: That code might not have been correct, I've updated it